# Getting parent categories sum(price) formed in different tables

Tags: mysql

I am trying to get the total prices of all parent categories in a specific month and year. A parent category is any category with a parent_id == 0. My query is like below:

```
SELECT
    ROUND(SUM(od.total_price)) as price, 
    c.parent_id as pId,
    c1.name
FROM a_orders o 
    INNER JOIN a_order_details as od on o.id = od.order_id 
    INNER JOIN a_product as p on p.id = od.product_id 
    INNER JOIN a_category as c on c.id = p.category_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN a_category c1 ON c.parent_id = c1.id
WHERE YEAR(order_date) = 2018
    AND o.STAT = 'Y' 
    AND MONTH(order_date) = 6
GROUP BY c.parent_id;
```

I'm getting parent categories just which have a price but I need to get all parent categories, if there is no price result should be 0.

My sqlfiddle is -> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b9f4c1/1

My result is like this :

```
price   pId  name
410     1    T-SHIRT
400     2    JEANS
```

But should be like this :

```
price   pId  name
410     1    T-SHIRT
400     2    JEANS
0       6    SHOES
```

Comment: you can erase your comments here if you want, thanks for clarifying your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this you need switch your logic around. First select all of your parent categories, then join your order data.  This way you can ensure all of the desired categories will be included in the results.

There are a bunch of ways you could approach this — here I created a subquery with all of the order data and then a `LEFT JOIN` with the category table:

```
SELECT
    IFNULL(ROUND(SUM(orders.total_price)),0) AS price, 
    c.id AS pId,
    c.name
FROM a_category c
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT od.total_price, c.parent_id
        FROM a_orders o 
            INNER JOIN a_order_details od ON o.id = od.order_id 
            INNER JOIN a_product p ON p.id = od.product_id 
            INNER JOIN a_category c ON c.id = p.category_id
        WHERE YEAR(order_date) = 2018
            AND o.STAT = 'Y' 
            AND MONTH(order_date) = 6
    ) orders ON orders.parent_id = c.id
WHERE c.parent_id = 0
GROUP BY c.id;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b9f4c1/3